# What are the solutions of the equation $\phi (x) =p$ with p an prime number, x an integer and $\phi $ the Euler function.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> What are the solutions of the equation $\phi (x) =p$ with p an prime number, x an integer and $\phi $ the Euler function.

I have actually no idea how to start with solving this problem.

Comment: A start is to compute $\varphi(n)$ for the first $10$ natural numbers.

Comment: Are you familiar with a formula to calculate $\phi$ ?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $\phi(x)$ is almost always even.

*Solution:*

> $\phi(x)=1$ for $x\le 2$ and $\phi(x)$ is even for $x\ge3$. So $\phi(x)=p$ with $p$ prime only for $p=2$. The solutions of $\phi(x)=2$ are $x=3,4,6$ because if $q$ and $r$ are two different primes dividing $x$, then $(q-1)(r-1)$ divides $\phi(x)$.

Comment: Yes, x can also not have that many primefactors, I think. (max 2, I think)